# Toggle display of sidebar menu in shinydashboard programmatically

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working with R shiny dashboard and was wondering if I can collapse/show the sidebar with an additional button, just like the already existing one on top of the sidebar.
Is that possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add / remove the needed css class to / from the body via `shinyjs`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("toggle_btn", "Toggle sidebar")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$toggle_btn, {
    shinyjs::toggleClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]